# Add labels in nested pie graph (in R)

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have created a nested pie graph for my data:
Inner pie chart (coding=35, nc=25)
Outer pie chart (coding: c_tsg=31, c_ntsg=4, nc: nc_tsg=20, nc_ntsg=5)

Could you please tell me how can I add labels (the value of each variable) in the middle of their sections of the pie charts?
Thanks

Here is my code:

```
library('plotrix')

## input
total=58
coding=33
nc=25
c_tsg=30
c_ntsg=3
nc_tsg=20
nc_ntsg=5

# initial radius
iniR=0.2 
colors=list(NO='white',total='black',coding='#e5f5e0',nc='#a1d99b',
            c_tsg='#3182bd',c_ntsg='#fec44f',nc_tsg='#fc9272',nc_ntsg='#9ecae1')

pie(1, radius=iniR, init.angle=90, col=c('white'), border = NA, labels='')

# pie chart for divide coding and nc into tsg and ntsg
floating.pie(0,0,c(c_tsg, coding-c_tsg, nc_tsg, nc-nc_tsg),radius=3*iniR, startpos=pi/2, col=as.character(colors[c('c_tsg','NO','c_ntsg','NO')]),border=NA)

# pie chart for coding + nc
floating.pie(0,0, c(coding, nc), radius=2*iniR, startpos=pi/2, col=as.character(colors[c('coding','nc')]), border = NA)
```

Comment: Perhaps the only way is to manually set the coordinates of the labels in the `text` function.